# How to Modify core Module webapi.xml in Magento2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2-api

Magento 2 **Core API** to get products in `GET` method but want to make it `POST` method .

How to do it and also open API ?

Answer (score 1):

in Your custom module create webapi.xml in etc folder and  paste below code

```
<route url="/V1/products/lists" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

and below is the code to call API in curl

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Authentication rest API magento2.Please change url accordingly your url
//$url = 'http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%simple%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like';


// POST Method 
$url = 'http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/rest/V1/products/lists';
$searchCriteria['searchCriteria']['filter_groups'][0]['filters'][0]['field']='sku';
$searchCriteria['searchCriteria']['filter_groups'][0]['filters'][0]['value']='%simple%';
$searchCriteria['searchCriteria']['filter_groups'][0]['filters'][0]['condition_type']='like';

$data_string = json_encode($searchCriteria);
echo '<pre>'; echo $data_string;echo '------<br>';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$datas = curl_exec($ch);
echo $datas; 
$datas = json_decode($datas);
print_r($datas);
```